# Accessing the internal phone memory by swapping out the SIM card

Tags: security, google-account, internal-storage, sim-card

Is it possible to access an Android phone's internal memory by switching out the SIM card?

My Android phone, with no SD card, has been stolen but access to the phone is locked via the "graphical pin".

Will it be possible to read internal memory after changing the SIM card? I am concerned mainly with the Gmail password I have stored on there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Gmail will ask you to login again if it detects change of SIM card.
2. Gmail doesn't store your credentials in internal memory unencrypted.
3. Phone has to be rooted to read from internal memory.
4. Your phone can't be unlocked without the correct graphical PIN combination.

Comment: Will starting the phone in safe mode retain the lock screen or does it bypass the lockscreen?

Comment: It will retain the lock screen.

Comment: How about gmail application and already downloaded threads? Has the lock screen some limit of unlocking attempts? Thanks

Comment: @Steffen: I believe this is configurable, but from what I've observed, it's 5 attempts 'til a cooldown period of 30 seconds.  During this cooldown period, you'll have an opportunity to use your Google Account password as an alternative way to unlock your screen.

Comment: @Steffen: As for your Gmail, although all communication with the Gmail Server is encrypted, synced messages are stored in the clear on your phone.  However, as long as you haven't rooted it (and as long as your bootloader is locked, and your operating system is up to date), this database should be safe from other applications.  If you want to ensure that someone couldn't somehow read what's on the internal storage without going through the operating system, consider full-phone encryption.

Comment: @ctt: so if I did not rooted it, then it can't be rooted now, when it is locked with the graphical pin? This sounds like reasonable protection. I wonder how many combinations has the gfx pin

Comment: Unless there's some sort of backdoor in the operating system, the only way to root your phone involves unlocking the bootloader.  Unlocking the boot loader involves wiping your phone, which gets rid of any data you hope to be hiding.  So you're pretty safe